# Как можно исправить метод news, чтобы получить на выходе 123456789 и 987654321 не изменяя аргументов в методе end.....?

Tags: java, циклы, for

Как можно исправить метод news, чтобы получить на выходе 123456789 и 987654321 не изменяя аргументов в методе end.....?

```
public class Class2 {
  void start() {
    end();
  }

  void news(int a, int b, int c) {
    for (int i = a; i != b; i = i + c) {
      System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
  }

  void end() {
    news(1, 9, 1);
    news(9, 1, -1);
  }
```

```
Результат...

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно вывести значение `b` после цикла в методе `news`.

Также может понадобиться валидация аргументов в методе `news`:

1. обязательно `c != 0`;
2. если `a < b`, то должно быть `c > 0`;
3. если `a > b`, то должно быть `c < 0`

иначе результат может сильно отличаться от ожидаемого.

```java
void news(int a, int b, int c) {
    if (c == 0 || (a < b && c < 0) || (a > b && c > 0)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format(
            "Bad arguments: a=%d, b=%d, c=%d", a, b, c
        ));
    }
    for (int i = a; i != b; i += c) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
    System.out.print(b);
    System.out.println();
}
```